# Add/Remove more rows dynamically using jquery and jstl dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, jsp, jstl

I want to add new rows with select dropdown list using jQuery while clicking on `addrow` button.

So I am using JSTL tags in my jsp file to create dropdown list.

When I create new row using `addrow` button using jQuery, I want this new dropdown list to show the same values (`countryList`) as of default dropdown list which is created for the first time (before clicking add new row button).

How to create the rows using jQuery?

SimpleFormController:

```
protected Map referenceData(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    Map referenceData = new HashMap();
    Map<String,String> country = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
    country.put("US", "United Stated");
    country.put("CHINA", "China");
    country.put("SG", "Singapore");
    country.put("MY", "Malaysia");
    referenceData.put("countryList", country);
}
```

form:options:

```
<form:select path="country">
   <form:option value="NONE" label="--- Select ---"/>
   <form:options items="${countryList}" />
</form:select>
```

Example:

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/PuWMK/2/)

Note : Above jsFiddle is just for reference.

Comment: As you have already populated dropdown list . You can just use jquery .clone() method and append it to the div area. No need to again populate country list from the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Hello this should't be a problem to do it like this:

```
    //Execute this on button click
$('#countries').append($('<option>',
 {
    value: "China",
    text : "China"
}));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b734fgcf/

The html and js are executed after the generated jsp, to it should be like just a normal HTML Jquery modification. If you would like to send this data back to the server, there might be some security problem about it. Good Luck :)