# Setting the first value as default in dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery

Jquery to create new row :

```
var selectVal = $(parent).children().first().find('select').find('option[selectedGivenTo="true"]').val();
    var newSelect = $(parent).children().last().find('select');
    newSelect.each(function() {
        var cloned  = null;
        cloned = $(this).clone();
        cloned.val(selectVal);
```

I am trying to select the first value of dropdownlist as default value using jQuery as above but no value is selected & just displaying list in dropdown.I saw many references in stackoverflow but its not working for me.

Comment: I'm confused as to the problem you're trying to solve as you get this behaviour by default when creating a new `select`. Could you show a working example of your problem, including all relevant JS code and the HTML

Comment: Can you post the HTML? Are you using any plugin for dropdownlist?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39024914/add-remove-more-rows-dynamically-using-jquery-and-jstl-dropdown please look at this ..this is want i want to do but with JSTL tags and not normal html..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select it by value, then use the code below:

```
$('select option[value="defaultValue"]').attr("selected",true);
```

If you want to select via text contains in option, use the following code:

```
$('select option:contains("I am defualt Value")').prop('selected',true);
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function(){
$("select option:first").attr('selected','selected');
             var _select = $('select')[0],
       _v = _select.options[_select.selectedIndex].value;
       alert(_v);
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rajee2686/znmrLd1f/2/)